# Access Object in FormRequest in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm passing an object next to my form request like so:

```
public function updateTrade(SendTradeRequest $request, Trade $trade)
```

How can I access the Trade $trade object that was sent with this request in SendTradeRequest in the rules() section?

Comment: use `$this->route('trade')` or `Route::current()->getParameter('trade');`

Comment: if I use this, it returns an empty object, not a filled one, while it should be filled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is 2 ways to get binded entity in form request:

1. `$this->trade`
2. `$this->route('trade')`

Comment: I've bound trade in RouteServiceProvider like `Route::model('trade', \App\Trade::class);` and call `$this->trade` in `rules()` however it returns a non-object `message
:
"Trying to get property of non-object"`